# change the text of asp:textbox placeholder using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to change the text of the placeholder of asp:textbox using jquery?
i tried to use:

```
   $('#textbox1').attr("placeholder", "enter some text");
```

but nothing happens
below is my asp textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" placeholder="Text" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Use this one `$('#<%: textbox1.ClientID %>').attr("placeholder", "enter some text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a few elements to the jQuery so that it will find the textbox you are looking for:

```
$("#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>").attr("placeholder", "enter some text");
```

Since you are using an 'asp:TextBox', when the webpage is compiled, .Net adds values to it's ID, resulting in the ID of the textbox no longer being equal to 'textbox1'. By using `<%=textbox1.ClientID %>` it allows you to search for the original ID that you named the textbox in the code.

For Example: 
In one of my webpages, I have this textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nameTextBox" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I run my webpage and look at the compiled version of the html code, its ID is now this:

```
id="ctl00_Content_propertiesDXCallbackPanel_nameTextBox"
```

As you can see .Net has added data to the ID  of the textbox to allow it to use it, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what is actualy happening is that `$('#textbox1')` will not actually return any elements. That is because jQuery will look for an element with the exact ID `textbox1`, and ASP.NET by default generates dynamic IDs for elements.

So your `<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" ... />` will actually get rendered out as something like `<input id="ctl00_someOtherDynamicStuff_textbox1" type="text"/>` **(note the ID)**.

One solution is to give your TextBox a class you can select it by: `<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" CssClass="someClassName" runat="server"/>`

and then use that in your JS:

```
$('.someClassName').attr("placeholder", "enter some text");
```